# facebook integration in ionic 2 platform

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am newbie in developing the hybrid app (ionic 2). I was looking for some sort of help in integrating facebook login in my ionic2 app .But couldn't find any relevant help. 
Any sort of help will be useful.
Thanks

Comment: What backend are you planning on using?

Comment: @gerdi We are planning to have your backend in .Net platform. Does it have to do something with the integration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this tutorial in order to implement facebook login in ionic 2. It doesn't really matter which platform you are going to use for backend.

https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic2-facebook-login

Comment: have a look at this repo.  https://github.com/fuffenz/ionic2-native-facebook-login